# Media queries loading styles from higher resolution stylesheet - why?

Tags: media, responsive-design

Please can someone point me in the right direction! I can't get the queries to work as intended.

So, I have for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/480.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:480px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/768.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:768px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/960.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:960px)" />
```

In the 480 stylesheet:

```
#box{width:100px;height:100px;}
```

In the 960 stylesheet:

```
#box{width:200px;height:200px;}
```

When I resize the browser to 480px or less the 960 style is overriding the 480 style. I have tried loading all queries in the one stylesheet and I've tried using separate stylesheets for different resolutions but still not working. When testing it in either Chrome or FF Aurora it makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px),
screen and (max-width: 960px) {
#box{width:100px;height:100px;outline:1px solid red;}
}
/* Still small! (but scaling up) */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
#box{width:200px;height:200px;outline:1px solid red;}
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sthAngels/EecJD/

Comment: Using this as thinking between the 2 parameters (480px and 980px) seems to work best for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for me:
http://felixebert.de/so-12811458/

- Is the path to the css files correct?
- Is the HTML Doctype correct (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)?
- Do you mix an id-reference with a class-reference? (#box = `<div id="box" />`, .box = `<div class="box" />`)
- What's in 768.css?

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks. I see your example works fine but mine is still overriding. The paths to the CSS are correct. In Firebug you can see the style for 480 crossed out and the style for 960 being used...